# Can't use bootstrap navbar on my rails with webpacker app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpacker

Hi I am running my app using webpacker with ruby on rails.
I am trying to figure out why was the navbar I am using not opening up. it always comes with no styling. Shown in the image:
[image]

I am using the navbar from [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/rainbow-nav)

This is my `environment.js` file for `webpacker`:
I already installed `bootstrap` using `yarn`.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const path = require('path')

environment.use = [
  {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              "includePaths": [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
              ]
            }
          },{
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
            options: {
              attempts: 1
            }
          }
]

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': "jquery",
    Tether: 'tether',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment;
```

I can get the jquery working on my app. but bootstrap is not loading into my app. And how do I use bootstrap global without requiring it anywhere? is it possible? if not, how would I require it in one place and use it everywhere? Is it at `application.js` file?

I see that the nav-bar I am using is always viewed as mobile view. The `navbar-toggle collapse` class should be in collapse, but the class it has is `navbar-toggle collapsed`. when on web view as well. And the `navbar-collapse collapsed` class used on web view should be `collapsed`, but it has class `collapse`. After manual changing the classes from developer console. I found this view(with no styling):
[image]

Comment: Check if `<head>` contains calls to css and js files. I see 6 errors in your dev tab.

Comment: those are warnings on Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.